# Using PHP to stop users from downloading code, but code is cpu intensive

Tags: php, javascript

I have some proprietary formulas that is used to calculate some vehicle dynamic stuff. I have it all in a php file and the user gets access to this from ajax in the javascript on the client side.

I believe by doing this the user can never get access to the formulas in the php script, is this true (If I have the access setup correctly)?

The actual problem I have is, there are probably 80 equations and this is run in a loop 200 times to obtain the final answers and its cpu intensive. Running 1 is fine, but if I had 10 people using the site it will slow down the server.

I cant put all the formulas on the client side or else he can download them. And I cant put say 90% of the equations on the client side and leave the rest on the server because then I would have to go back and forward with ajax 200 times inside the loop just to obtain the answers once.

What are my options to get stuff done on the client side but protect the formulas?

Comment: This is usually done using some kind of offline queue coupled with long polling or whatnot, so only one is ever being calculated at a time.

Comment: Note, some hosts offer things like background workers, such as [Pagoda Box](http://help.pagodabox.com/customer/portal/articles/430779) (I am not affiliated other than having a free site). The technique is, you have the client request the data, show the user a wait screen, and then setup the request for the background worker to consume, and use `sleep()` to check if the background worker has consumed the request and given a result, in which case it is returned to the client, or a timeout occurs (which you would have to handle).

Comment: As a side note, if you ever update your website and a BACKUP file gets loaded ... `myfile.php.bak` or `myfile.php~` then someone COULD request that file and see its contents.

Comment: I never understood how one can try to build a whole business just on trying to keep a few lines secret...

Comment: @arkascha Google's algorith for displaying results is a top secret, and they have gone so far...

Comment: You mention the code is CPU intensive, how long does all of the code take to execute? (1 run of all 80 equations, done 200 times)

Comment: @Oriol: No, actually Google's algorithm is well known and public. It is a patented algorithm, however. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run code on the client side without letting the client side see that code. You can obfuscate your code, but for something like mathematical equations I doubt there is going to be much in the way of obfuscation you can do that will obscure the content enough to prevent someone from figuring out what the equations are.

Your options are:

- Invest in some better hardware so that your server can handle more users. This might mean running the calculations on a tier different than your web server tier.
- Optimize your equations. This might mean re-implementing them in C as a PHP extension module, or at least enabling an opcode cache.